# Generate a date eight business days after the dateReceived field into the firstFollowUp field on my form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form where I input information for paperwork processed with the date the paperwork was received.

I need to generate a date eight business days after the dateReceived, in a new field called firstFollowUp, to follow up on the status of paperwork.

I'm mostly familiar with VBA, but I'm open to other suggestions.

I get a syntax error on the Format lines. Also, I'm not sure this does what I want it to.

```
Function Work_Days(dateReceived As Variant, firstFollowUp As Variant) As Long

Dim wholeWeeks As Variant
Dim dateCount As Variant
Dim endDays As Integer

wholeWeeks = DateDiff("w", dateReceived, firstFollowUp)
dateCount = DateAdd("ww", wholeWeeks, dateReceived)
endDays = 0

Do While dateCount <= firstFollowUp
    If Format(dateCount, "ddd")<> "Sun" And Format(dateCount, "ddd")<> "Sat" Then
        endDays = endDays + 1
    End If

    dateCount = DateAdd("d", 1, dateCount)
Loop
Work_Days = wholeWeeks * 5 + endDays

Exit Function
```

Comment: Can you explain if this is a problem with VB.NET or a problem with VBA? They are two very different languages and you should not use irrelevant tags for your problem

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `DatePaperworkReceived` is your form control for the "date the paperwork was received", add this to the "AfterUpdate" event for `DatePaperworkReceived`.

Me.firstFollowUp=DateAdd('d',8,Me.DatePaperworkreceived)

For business days, instead of 8, you would use:

```
IIf(Weekday(Me.DatePaperworkreceived)=7,13,IIF(Weekday(Me.DatePaperworkreceived)>3,12,10))
```

If you are assured the received date will not fall on the weekend it can be simplified:

```
IIF(Weekday(Me.DatePaperworkreceived)>3,12,10)
```

Comment: This looks great, but I need it to generate a date 8 business days later, not calendar days.

Comment: Ah, and I assume you define business days as Monday-Friday? I will try to post some code that achieves that. It will account for weekends but not for any holidays, there is no easy way to account for that unless you want to add a holiday calendar table to your project.

Comment: Yes, Monday through Friday. I am not too concerned with holidays at the moment, but if the date I received the paperwork is 02/06/19, I need it to generate 02/18/19 in the firstFollowUp field.

Comment: I have the following, but its not working.

 Private Sub dateReceived_AfterUpdate() 
 Me.firstFollowUp=DateAdd('d',IIF(Weekday(Me.dateReceived)>3,12,10),Me.dateReceived)
End Sub

Comment: Do you get an error? Or just nothing happening? `AfterUpdate` only runs after you tab out of the control.

Comment: An error pops up and my whole line of code appears in red when I tab out of the control. It says "Compile error: Syntax Error"

Comment: Try using "d" instead of 'd'. Also check for mismatched parenthesis.

Comment: YES!!!! It works, thank you sooo much! The problem was the 'd'. It needs to be "d".

Comment: What would it be for 5 business days instead of 8 business days?

Answer (score 0):

I found in one of my old Access applications code which calculates next business days  but I do not know where do I have it from. Credits go to the coder who did it. I may be useful:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Function AddWorkDaysA(lngDays As Long, _
Optional dtmDate As Date = 0, _
Optional adtmDates As Variant) As Date
    ' Add the specified number of work days to the
    ' specified date.

    ' In:
    '   lngDays:
    '       Number of work days to add to the start date.
    '   dtmDate:
    '       date on which to start looking.
    '       Use the current date, if none was specified.
    '   adtmDates (Optional):
    '       Array containing holiday dates. Can also be a single
    '       date value, if that's what you want.
    ' Out:
    '   Return Value:
    '       The date of the working day lngDays from the start, taking
    '       into account weekends and holidays.
    ' Example:
    '   AddWorkDaysA(10, #2/9/2019#, Array(#2/18/2019#, #2/20/2019#))
    '   returns #2/26/2019#, which is the date 10 work days
    '   after 2/9/2019, if you treat 2/18 and 2/20 as holidays


    ' Did the caller pass in a date? If not, use
    ' the current date.
    Dim lngCount As Long
    Dim dtmTemp As Date

    If dtmDate = 0 Then
        dtmDate = Date
    End If

    dtmTemp = dtmDate
    For lngCount = 1 To lngDays
        dtmTemp = NextWorkdayA(dtmTemp, adtmDates)
    Next lngCount
    AddWorkDaysA = dtmTemp
End Function

Public Function NextWorkdayA( _
Optional dtmDate As Date = 0, _
Optional adtmDates As Variant = Empty) As Date

    ' Return the next working day after the specified date.

    ' In:
    '   dtmDate:
    '       date on which to start looking.
    '       Use the current date, if none was specified.
    '   adtmDates (Optional):
    '       Array containing holiday dates. Can also be a single
    '       date value.
    ' Out:
    '   Return Value:
    '       The date of the next working day, taking
    '       into account weekends and holidays.
    ' Example:
    '   ' Find the next working date after 5/24/19
    '   dtmDate = NextWorkdayA(#5/24/19#, #5/27/19#)
    '   ' dtmDate should be 5/28/19, because 5/27/19 is Memorial day.

    ' Did the caller pass in a date? If not, use
    ' the current date.
    If dtmDate = 0 Then
        dtmDate = Date
    End If

    NextWorkdayA = SkipHolidaysA(adtmDates, dtmDate + 1, 1)
End Function

Private Function SkipHolidaysA( _
adtmDates As Variant, _
dtmTemp As Date, intIncrement As Integer) As Date
    ' Skip weekend days, and holidays in the array referred to by adtmDates.
    ' Return dtmTemp + as many days as it takes to get to a day that's not
    ' a holiday or weekend.

    Dim strCriteria As String
    Dim strFieldName As String
    Dim lngItem As Long
    Dim blnFound As Boolean

    On Error GoTo HandleErrors

    ' Move up to the first Monday/last Friday, if the first/last
    ' of the month was a weekend date. Then skip holidays.
    ' Repeat this entire process until you get to a weekday.
    ' Unless adtmDates an item for every day in the year (!)
    ' this should finally converge on a weekday.

    Do
        Do While IsWeekend(dtmTemp)
            dtmTemp = dtmTemp + intIncrement
        Loop
        Select Case VarType(adtmDates)
            Case vbArray + vbDate, vbArray + vbVariant
                Do
                    blnFound = FindItemInArray(dtmTemp, adtmDates)
                    If blnFound Then
                        dtmTemp = dtmTemp + intIncrement
                    End If
                Loop Until Not blnFound
            Case vbDate
                If dtmTemp = adtmDates Then
                    dtmTemp = dtmTemp + intIncrement
                End If
        End Select
    Loop Until Not IsWeekend(dtmTemp)

ExitHere:
    SkipHolidaysA = dtmTemp
    Exit Function

HandleErrors:
    Resume ExitHere
End Function

Private Function IsWeekend(dtmTemp As Variant) As Boolean
    ' If your weekends aren't Saturday (day 7) and Sunday (day 1),
    ' change this routine to return True for whatever days
    ' you DO treat as weekend days.

    If VarType(dtmTemp) = vbDate Then
        Select Case Weekday(dtmTemp)
            Case vbSaturday, vbSunday
                IsWeekend = True
            Case Else
                IsWeekend = False
        End Select
    End If
End Function

Private Function FindItemInArray(varItemToFind As Variant, _
avarItemsToSearch As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim lngItem As Long

    On Error GoTo HandleErrors

    For lngItem = LBound(avarItemsToSearch) To UBound(avarItemsToSearch)
        If avarItemsToSearch(lngItem) = varItemToFind Then
            FindItemInArray = True
            GoTo ExitHere
        End If
    Next lngItem

ExitHere:
    Exit Function

HandleErrors:
    Resume ExitHere
End Function
```

Just use it like this:

```
 firstFollowUp.Text = AddWorkDaysA (8, yourDateFiled.Text, Array(#1/1/2019#, #2/18/2019#, #5/27/2019#, #4/4/2019#))
```